# Why is JAX-RS parameter empty when message body is not?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS Web service I'm writing and it is consuming a JSON message body. The issue is the parameter that is supposed to contain the body is always empty.

```
@Path("/")
public class MyClass {

    @Path("/echo")
    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response echo(String message, @QueryParam("action") String action) {
        System.out.println(message);
        System.out.println(action);
        return Response.status(200).build();
    }

}
```

In this example, action will always contain the correct content but message will always be empty. From other questions I have been lead to believe that all that is needed to access the body is to provide a parameter to store it. For reasons out of my control, I cannot couple the JSON directly into an object like it is probably best practice to to.

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>authenticate</groupId>
  <artifactId>authenticate</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
        <version>2.27</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
version="4.0">
  <display-name>authenticate</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>
      jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>au.com.biting.bolat</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is apparently with Jersey only passing along the content if the type in the parameter matches what the web service is annotated as being able to consume. My solution is to just annotate the method with

```
@Consumes
```

Instead of

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

And the raw JSON gets passed into the String now.

Comment: I would argue that something like `MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN` would be better (or whatever the `Content-Type` HTTP header is sending).  As it is it would accept anything.

Comment: The idea behind this was being able to have a client send JSON as its content type, and receive the actual content as a string and doing either of those things would prevent me from being able to do this. I have added a bit to my code to throw a 415 if what comes back isn't actually JSON. Probably not best practice but it will do for this purpose.